# Use perl regular expression to match a pattern that spans multiple lines in SAS

Tags: html, regex, sas

I have an HTML snippet like this stored in html.html:

```
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Areas of interest</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Interest</li>   
    <li>Interest</li>  
  </ul>
  <h4>Other</h4>
</body>
```

I have build a REGEX pattern `(/<\/h4>(\w*\W*)*<h4>/)` that matches the pattern to extract everything between first `</h4>` tag and second `<h4>` tag, but how do I get SAS to search for a pattern across the multiple lines?

SAS Code:

```
filename html; 

data interests (drop=pattern);
   length string $2500;
   IF _N_ = 1 THEN
      PATTERN = PRXPARSE("/<\/h4>(\w*\W*)*<h4>/");
   RETAIN PATTERN;
   infile html LRECL=2500;
   string $CHAR2500.;
   IF PRXMATCH(PATTERN,STRING) GT 0 THEN OUTPUT;
run;
```

Currently I am getting blank results.

Comment: Try `PATTERN = PRXPARSE("/(?<=<\/h4>).*?(?=<h4>)/s");`. Also, how about using [an HTML parser](http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html)?

Comment: Why is this tagged Perl?

Comment: @DaveCross Because of the natural expression which is a feature of PERL.

Comment: @stribizhev Sorry if it is not clear, but the problem is with SAS code, not PERL expression. Perl expression matches the lines, I have tested it in online testers such as http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: @VasilijNevlev: do not use `(\w*\W*)*`. It is VERY inefficient and will cause catastrophic backtracking sooner than later. Use `[\w\W]*?`.

Comment: You mean "regular expression", not "natural expression". And aren't regular expressions a feature of pretty much any Unix tool? Why not tag it "sed", "awk", "python" or "PHP"?

Comment: @DaveCross Ok, you won. It is not a perl question

Comment: Perl regexes are obviously different to SAS regexes. If this was in Perl, then your current regex would not match your example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it this way in SAS.

SAS sees each row of your html as a separate observation; if you want to parse them as a whole you'd need some logic to join them together.  What follows is an example that works on your sample code, but probably would fail on tons of special cases.  As commenters have indicated, you might be better off using an html parser if you can.

This example starts (or restarts) line concatenation when it sees a `<h4>` and outputs the concatenated line when it sees a `</h4>`.

```
data interests (keep=multiline);
    length multiline $250;
    set html;
    string = trim(string);
    retain multiline;
    multiline = cats(multiline,string);
    if find(string,'<h4>') > 0 then multiline = string;
    if find(string,'</h4>') > 0 then do;
        output;
        multiline = '';
    end;
run;
```

Comment: I am glad you confirmed that I can't make SAS to ingest multiple lines at the same time. I was leaning towards concatenation myself and today I implemented a version of your code, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The way to have SAS search across multiple lines is to change how SAS defines "line".

For example, you can use `recfm=n`, which tells SAS just to consider the file a stream of bytes with no concept at all of line.  You can also use `recfm=f`, which sets a fixed line size (which can be arbitrarily large up to the maximum capacity of the machine, though 32767 is a maximum if you want to use `_infile_`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data want;
   infile 'path\yourhtml' truncover;
   length string $100;
   input @;
   if index(_infile_,'h4')>0 then do;
      string=prxchange('s/.*\>(.*)\<.*/$1/i',-1,_infile_);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Hey Shenglin, 
Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately it manages to extract the heading between h4 tags, but not the points underneath it. The reason being your code only checks one line at the time. Thanks for suggestion.